# How can I get I get the thumbnail custom size dimensions?

Tags: thumbnails, images

Assuming I have a custom thumbnail size, as defined by the following...

```
add_image_size( $name, $dim_x, $dim_y, true );
```

...how can I get the defined image dimensions programatically, using only $name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the look at the source of the function is simply stores the arguments in `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` global, with key by name.

As far as I remember there are no dedicated API functions for it (`get_intermediate_image_sizes()` will return list of names, but not data). Just access the global and look for data you need by key.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer given by Rarst, I was able to find [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes) in the Wordpress documentation...

```
function get_image_sizes( $name ) {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    $sizes = array();
    $get_intermediate_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    // Create the full array with sizes and crop info
    foreach( $get_intermediate_image_sizes as $_size ) {
            if ( in_array( $_size, array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large' ) ) ) {
                    $sizes[ $_size ]['width'] = get_option( $_size . '_size_w' );
                    $sizes[ $_size ]['height'] = get_option( $_size . '_size_h' );
                    $sizes[ $_size ]['crop'] = (bool) get_option( $_size . '_crop' );
            } elseif ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ] ) ) {
                    $sizes[ $_size ] = array( 
                            'width' => $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['width'],
                            'height' => $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['height'],
                            'crop' =>  $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['crop']
                    );
            }
    }
    // Get only 1 size if found
    if ( $size ) {
            if( isset( $sizes[ $size ] ) ) {
                    return $sizes[ $size ];
            } else {
                    return false;
            }
    }
    return $sizes;
}
```

---

```
<?php 
    var_dump(get_image_sizes('custom-size'));
?>
```

---

```
array(3) {
    ["width"] => int(250)
    ["height"] => int(250)
    ["crop"] =>  bool(true)
}
```